# How can I extract only numbers from string using function in C?

Tags: c

As usual, I was trying to enhance my coding skills in C, so I took one exercise to practice. So it says that I should input to the string some value(there must be letters and numbers), then I must extract only numbers from this string using a function and output the result in `main`. So In fact, if I input for e.g: `sdasd5465`, it must output only `5465`.

So now I did write code but I can't tackle one problem. The compiler shows me an error in my function addressing one of my lines in `myfucntion` and gives an error: "Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector", pointing to this line `for(i=0; str[i];i++)`. Here the code, and I sincerely hope that I am asking the right question now)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int main() {
    char str[N];
    printf("String, pls : ");
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    myfunction(str);
    printf("After extracting : ");
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

void myfunction(char str){
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i=0; str[i] ;i++){

        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){
            str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: The function parameter should be `char *str`, closing as typo.

Comment: @anastaciu, oh year it worked but now it gives me a warning: implicit declaration of myfunction and conflicting types for myfunction. And function doesn't work.

Comment: you need to declare the function before main.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the isdigit function from standard library.

If you are on linux use the man pages for the description or just google it.

Answer (score 0):

A typical [running pointer](https://wiki.c2.com/?TortoiseAndHare) algorithm. A simple novice function might look like this:

```
void myfunction(char *str){
    int outputidx = 0;
    for (int inputidx = 0; str[inputidx] != '\0'; inputidx++) {
        if (isdigit(str[inputidx])) {
              str[outputidx] = str[inputidx];
              outputidx++;
        }
    }
    str[outputidx] = '\0';
}
```